# Show Laravel SoftDeleted Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

i'm facing an issue, im not sure if this issn't a feature. Problem is as following. I created a Device Database where the User can create, manuipulate, soft delete and delete devices.

On my index page i'm able to shows all devices even the softdeleted (as it should be).
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw8zz.png)

But when i click on an device (show method), to see the details of the device, i get an 404 on softdeleted devices.

When requesting the Model via Tinker i get the model. When i remove the deleted_at timestamp i can access the device details. So it seems i can not access softdeleted models via the show method.

I search the web but i only find the ->withTrashed() on my query. But for the show method i don`t have any query for my device itself because it comes within the paramter. The method itself seems not getting any 'device' as parameter.
Is it somehow possible to change this behaviour, so i can first view the softdeleted device before restoring it. Or did i miss some kind of flag or reference in another file?

Here my show mehtod:

```php
public function show(Device $device)
  {
    $connected_devices = Device::where('connected_to', $device->id)->get();
    $comments = DeviceComment::where('device_id', $device->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return view('devices.show', ['device' => $device, 'connected_devices' => $connected_devices, 'comments' => $comments]);
  }
```

But i guess i have to something before because when i add 'dd' at the first line it does not show my dd i still get 404.

Kind regards
Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, please add your current code you have written so far.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to show the model? Are you using route model binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose Laravel returns 404 because before going to controller it is trying to load your model. By default query won't have ->withTrashed() method and you should change the query by yourself.

To clearly understand how it works, check the documentation about [Explicit bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding)

Comment: worked with the "Customizing The Resolution Logic" thanks a lot.